# Custom ticks are not shown on reacharts x axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

When I use the default ticks, it's shown. But when I use a custom tick function, it's not shown:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
    <LineChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
        }}
    >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis
            dataKey="name"
            tick={() => <div>hi</div>}
        />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
        <Line dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

If I remove the `tick` function, then labels are shown on the x axis. But when I want to show a simple `hi` message as test, nothing is shown:

This is the image without custom tick function:
[image]

And this is the image with custom tick function:
[image]

I have tried setting the `interval={0}` but that changes nothing. I followed [this](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1330) issue but none of the solutions worked.

What do I miss here?

The point is that those `<div>hi</div>` messages are rendered and I can see them in the SVG tags in the dev tools. But they are not shown. I changed the style too, but could not make them show.

Comment: <div> elements are not valid svg elements and cannot be nexted inside svg elements. Are you trying to display a div inside an svg?

Comment: @Undo, what should I show there?

Comment: I was asking if the tick function injects elements inside an svg, in that case, <div> won't work, you have to use svg elements like <g>, <rect> etc

Comment: @Undo, your note about nesting `div` in `svg` actually did the trick. I removed the `div` and used `<Text />` from the recharts library itself and it worked. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML elements are not valid inside SVG elements. It appears the rechart  authors have made a component [`<Text />`](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Text) to use as text which produces text in vector form which is valid svg and subsequently in the `tick` callback.